# Is $f(x) = x^T A x$ a convex function?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Is $f(x) = x^T A x$ a convex function, where  $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $A$ is a $ n\times n$ matrix?

If not, my question can be reformed to: when is $f(x)$ convex, any restriction for $A$? For example, like positive definite and symmetric?

Comment: This is not true. Assume $n=1$, $A=-1$, then $f(x)=-x^2$ which is concave.

Comment: Then when is it convex, should there be some restriction to A? like positive definite and symmetric?

Answer (score 12):

The necessary and sufficient condition for the function $f(x)=x^TAx$ to be convex is that $A+A^T$ is positive semidefinite.

Reason: $A+A^T$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, yes I got this Theorem from RockaFellar's book. But is the Hessian matrix of $f$ is $A$ or $A + A^T$'

Comment: It's $A+A^T$. Compare with the scalar case $A=(1)$: then $f(x)=x^2$ and $f''(x)=2$. This $2$ is secretly $1+1^T$.

Comment: But if 
A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1,2 \\
  3,4
 \end{pmatrix},  then $f(x) = x_1^2 + 3x_2 x_1 + 2x_1x_2+4x_2^2$, Hessian matrix is exactly $A$.

Comment: @Amanda The Hessian in your example is $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 2& 5 \\ 5& 8\end{array} \right] $. It is not A.  Eg. $\frac{\partial^2 x_1^2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1} = 2$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a convex function for any value of $n$. Let $A$ be the $n\times x$ matrix with $-1$ along the main diagonal and $0$ everywhere else. Then $f(x)=-||x||^2$ which is always a concave function.